# How to use script template in same html for a directive in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I prepared a template as the following

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="spinner.html">
        <div class="spinner">
          <div class="bounce1 spinner-bounce"></div>
          <div class="bounce2 spinner-bounce"></div>
          <div class="bounce3 spinner-bounce"></div>
          <div class="bounce4 spinner-bounce"></div>
          <div class="bounce5 spinner-bounce"></div>
        </div>
      </script>

    <!-- a couple of lines below -->

    <div spinner> </div>
```

with the following directive

```
app.directive('spinner', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: '#spinner.html'
    };
});
```

So, directive itself and its template are in the same html, `tempateUrl` is not loading `ng-template` I defined above. 
What is wrong with this? I tried `template` too but it didn't work too.

Comment: I think you have just to remove the `#` character

Comment: Sorry @Michelem, I forgot to mention, they are in the same page. Correcting that now.

Comment: It's working http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/r2L2ndsL/

Comment: Thanks, I'm digging it.

Comment: @Michelem I realized the problem after you post jsfiddle link. See the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realize the problem.

It's because I added `text/ng-template` template in the `<head>` tag, not `<body>` tag. In my case, it doesn't find my template and searches for `/spinner.html` on the server.